# JavaScript array value setting error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object

I was trying to make a small javascript game when I ran into a problem:
I couldn't set the value of previous segments in an array.

To make it more clear, here is an example:

```
for (var a = 0; a <= 100; a++) {
    if (grid[a].num == 2) {
        grid[a + 1].num++;
        grid[a - 1].num++;
        grid[a].num = 0;
    }
 }
```

The attribute 'num' of of `grid[a+1]` increased just fine, but nothing happened to the attribute 'num' of `grid[a-1]`.

Why does this happen and how can I get over this problem?

Comment: I answered your question and got a downvote because someone thinks I misunderstood what you were trying to calculate. Did I deduce your intentions correctly? Please try out my code and see if it does what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The value will not get updated, as the `grid[a-1]` returns a -ve value when a is 0, change the code as below.

```
for (var a = 0; a <= 100; a++) {
    if (grid[a].num == 2) {
        grid[a + 1].num++;
        if (a > 0) {
            grid[a - 1].num++;
        }
        grid[a].num = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: should probably also check that grid[a|a-1|a+1] exists (e.g. `if (grid[a+1] && grid[a-1] && grid[a])`).